# Element does not resize although it should

Tags: jquery, resize, grid, pinterest, jquery-isotope

I'm using the [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) plugin for pinterest like boxes, the only problem: if anything in the box changes (and changes the height of the box), then they overlap. To avoid that, I'm trying this:

```
$('#container').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector : '.box'
});

$(".special").click(function() {
    $(this).append("I'm a <strong>special</strong> box!");
    $('#container').isotope({'reLayout'});
});
```

.. but it doesn't seem to work.

Please check out an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eELmb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `relayout` like this:

```
$('#container').isotope('reLayout');
```

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#relayout